# Display only sub categories of particular category

Tags: category

Here is the code which displays all the categories and sub categories

```
<?php echo $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(TRUE, 0, 'level-top'); ?>
```

I would like to display only subcategories of category id 10.

Comment: where did u add above code????

Answer (score 2):

IN the below code you pass the category ID's like 4 and got all the subcategories of category.

```
   <?php
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();

    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
    {
      $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
      if($_category->getIsActive()) {
        echo '<ul><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
        $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
        foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
        {
              $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
              if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                  echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
                  $sub_sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                  $sub_sub_subcats = $sub_sub_cat->getChildren();
                  foreach(explode(',',$sub_sub_subcats) as $sub_sub_subCatid)
                  {
                    $_sub_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_subCatid);
                    if($_sub_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                        echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
                    }
                  }
               }
         }
         echo '</ul>';
      }
    }

    ?>


        ?>
```

Comment: I've been trying to only show subcategories of a parent category on the side bar for a moment now. My case is, if I were to click on, let's say "MEN" on the megamenu, I want the sidebar to display only the sub-categories of "MEN" within the sidebar. Any ideas on this? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $categoryId = 10 ;  // get current category id
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ;
    $catList = explode(",", $category->getChildren();) ;
    foreach{$catList as $cat} 
    {
       $subcategory = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($cat) ;
       echo $subcategory->getName() ; 
    }
?>
```

It will display the second level. If you want to display further levels, put this code in recursive.

Comment: Hi no sub categories displays here with this code,, any idea why?

Comment: pl try this code - in line 3, syntax error is there.  $categoryId = 10 ;  // get current category id
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ;
$catList = explode(",", $category->getChildren()) ;
foreach ($catList as $cat)
{
   $subcategory = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($cat) ;
   echo $subcategory->getName()."<br>" ; 
}